# How can I trim the whitespace immediately preceding and following a given character in python?

Tags: python, string

I have a bunch of strings that look like this

```
s = '| this is      |     my  | made up        string '
```

I'd like to write a function that removes all the whitespace immediately preceeding and following the `|`'s. So running `myFunc(s, '|')` would return

```
'|this is|my|made up        string '
```

Obviously `strip()` is too powerful, as I'd like to respect some of the whitespace. How can I do this in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex replace.

```
import re

s = '| this is      |     my  | made up        string '
print(re.sub(r'\s*\|\s*', '|', s))
```

Will give this output -

```
'|this is|my|made up        string '
```

Answer (score 3):

You can `split` the the string at `|` then `trim` each substring and then `join` it again:

```
'|'.join([i.strip() for i in s.split('|')])
```

Comment: You don't need to make a whole list here; `'|'.join(i.strip() for i in s.split('|'))` works too.

Comment: I think this is fundamentally simpler than a regex